# Coexistence of Makefile- and header-defined options

Tags: makefile, preprocessor-directive

I am working in a FORTRAN code project where compilation decisions are taken in two files: a header file (`definitions.h`), which is included from the relevant FORTRAN files, and the `makefile`.  For example, the compiler, some sets of libraries, and the sort of parallelization allowed (MPI, OpenMP, or none) are chosen in the `makefile`, and the inclusion of some parts of the code is controled by `#define` directives in the header.

1. I don't like having to edit two different files to setup the compilation.  Is there a better approach?
2. Besides, both the `makefile` and the `definitions.h` files are under revision control.  This means that my fellow careless developers commit and push new versions of both files where they have only changed the compilation options enabled, therefore polluting the revision control history.  Ideally, at least the largest file (the `makefile`) would not have to be edited to set the compilation options.
3. In some cases, inconsistencies happen.  Typically, some combinations of libraries chosen in the `makefile` are incompatible with some sections of code selected by the `#define` directives.  Is there any way to check this properly?

   E.g., in order to stop compilation if `LIB1=LIBFOO` (in the `makefile`) and `bar` is defined to `1` (in the headers file), I was trying the following bit of code in the `makefile`

   ```
   ifeq ($(LIB1), LIBFOO)
       bar_status:=`grep -i '^[[:space:]]*\#define[[:space:]]*bar[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]' definitions.h | tail -n1 | grep -ic '^[[:space:]]*#define[[:space:]]*bar[[:space:]]*1[[:space:]]*'`
   ifeq ($(bar_status), 1)
       $(error ERROR: You are trying to compile the code with bar enabled in definitions.h, but this is incompatible with the library LIBFOO selected in the makefile)
   endif
   endif
   ```

   but (a) this is extremely ugly, and (b) apparently it is not working at all.  How can this be fixed?

---

I worked on 3., and I think I sort of have an answer for it: I add a new `.PHONY` target, `ini_check`, which is a requisite for the other relevant targets, and reads

```
ifeq ($(LIB1), LIBFOO)
    bar_value:=$(shell echo bar | cat definitions.h - | gcc -E -undef - 2>/dev/null | tail -n1)
endif

ini_check:
ifeq ($(LIB1), LIBFOO)
ifeq ($(bar_value), 1)
    $(error ERROR: You are trying to compile the code with bar enabled in definitions.h, but this is incompatible with the library LIBFOO selected in the makefile)
endif
endif
    @echo "Done with the initial check, starting compilation..."
```

Note that now I use the C preprocessor to get the value of the variable `bar` after parsing the header.

Comment: I don't know Fortran, so I'll just comment. Make can take command-line options to determine some of these choices (or take the most common options as defaults). If `#define` directives are incompatible with some libraries, you should get compiler errors; if you don't, you should edit the libraries until you do.

Comment: Command-line options should be avoided, all inputs should come from files.

Concerning your wanted compiler errors, I don't get them, and I cannot modify the libraries.  Besides, if they appeared at all, they would do so a few minutes after the compilation started.  I would like to implement the above-mentioned check, so that compilation aborts as soon as possible if inconsistencies are detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your policy to run Make without flags or arguments, you can still save yourself some grief by putting the relevant switches in an adjunct file (*not* under version control) which the makefile will `include`.

Parsing source files with Make as you've tried to do is, as you say, both ugly and difficult. And it's a nightmare to maintain. I recommend keeping two versions of `definitions.h` under version control in different directories; the same same Make logic that chooses libraries can choose the header file.

I don't know what kind of errors you're getting when your header file is "incompatible" with the libraries, but if the libraries have different interfaces, you may be able to deliberately invoke compiler errors by putting some library-specific calls in the header files. (And if they don't have different interfaces, you seem to have some bad implementation-dependent behavior.)

Finally, if "a few minutes" is too long to wait for such a compiler error, then you must be making such errors pretty often-- you might want to look into your procedures. (Also, if you've modified only one or two files, a build shouldn't take that long-- a daily build, yes, but not the kind you do several times an hour.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes, the implementation is full of bad practices, indeed.

Comment: E.g., some preprocessor options in `definitions.h` required OpenMP compilation, but it was possible to compile the code with them and without OpenMP enabled in the `makefile`.

Besides, we had many subroutines outside from any module, and the few modules that we had were used almost everywhere, so adding a new variable that had to be shared between a few subroutines ended up in a full recompilation of the code.

I started some code rearrangement, but geez, when I was trying the different compilation options, I was wasting too much time in meaningless or wrong ones!